# Modifying application.js takes 20 seconds for localhost to reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I am using Rails 4  on a mid 2012 Macbook Pro 13 inch and whenever I modify my `application.js`, the Rails app seems to be recompiling assets, which takes about 20 seconds, before it reloads the page. When I change HTML or CSS, it reloads instantly.

Here are the relevant files that may help in solving this issue:

`application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
#config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

`development.rb`:

```
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Those all look right to me. What are your system specs? Maybe a copout answer, but you might benefit from a faster CPU and hard drive.

Comment: How about running `rake assets:precompile` and then removing `application.js` from `public/assets/` ? This will prevent precompiling assets in real time apart from that removed one.

Comment: @Beerlington, Macbook Pro mid 2012. @Bartosz, I don't have a `public/assets/` folder. I had already removed it before.

Comment: @Jani, no that causes no css to be applied.

Comment: Any chance you're using a virtual machine for development?

Comment: No, OS X 10.9.1. On another Macbook Pro 13 inch retina display with SSD, it does reload instantly. But, it has Rails 3 on it. Could that be a factor?

Answer (score 0):

Simply restart the rails server, then reload your browser.

Comment: So every time I modify my javascript, I have to restart the rails server and reload my browser? Doesn't seem like much of a solution to me.

Comment: No, only when you edit `application.js` since it is part of the asset pipeline.